# Understanding the use of “before” in a programming task

Tags: algorithm, time

I am working on task http://poj.org/problem?id=1884. I didn't understand just one part of it:

*`Adjacent stations on each route are far enough apart to allow a train to accelerate to its maximum velocity before beginning to decelerate.`*

Does it mean that train is accelerating and then going in constant speed/velocity before it goes to deaccelrate or it is accelerating for longer period, and when it comes to max velocity, it is immediately going to deaccelerate?

Comment: what would you expect from a regular train? deaccelerate immediately? :)

Comment: “before” here means “at any time before”, rather than “just before”. In other words, it's the first of your explanation (the second one being also possible but only as a special case).

Comment: This has nothing to do with SO.

Comment: @Karoly Space ships are theorized to do that for interstellar flights: half way through the flight you turn the ship around and head home, so that when you reach your destination you are standing still.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yes, literally half of the way between the stations. The idea is that you accelerate for as long as you can, which gives you minimal travel time.

Comment: how is this relevant here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fist one, yes, "train is accelerating and then going in constant speed/velocity before it goes to deaccelrate".
Basically the train accelerates as much as it can, then maintains maximum speed for the journey, then brakes as approaches the station.
What they meant was: if the station were too close, trains would have to accelerate then brake before reaching peak speed to be able to stop in the next station, but you don't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

from the text:

> It remains at that maximum velocity until it begins to decelerate (at
>   the same constant rate) as it approaches the next station.

Comment: Wait, Then, I need one simple explanation. Look... I calculated on paper and total time to reach 15 miles (that first input) is 15,50 minutes. But, text says that 15,60 minutes is needed (half way, 15,60/2) and my application gives me answer like 7.75 minutes. What's wrong?

Comment: @user2781703: impossible to tell. these numbers don't mean anything to me.

Comment: How do you mean? It needs 0.5 minutes to accelerate and deaccelerate. While 15 miles is 79200 feets, it will lose 1320 feets to accelerate and deaccelerate (max velocity = 5280, acceleration = 10560), so 79200-2640 => 76560 feets is remained. With speed od 5280 f/m, it will take 14,5 minutes to reach that area (with max velocity). So 14,5 + 0,5 + 0,5 = 15, 5. Half of it is 7,75, not 7,8. Is there any other trick?

Comment: sry, but I'm not going to check all your calculations...